# AWS IAM - S3: "Error putting S3 server side encryption configuration: AccessDenied" even when I am the Administrator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am the admin of my AWS account `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` policy assigned to my, that gives permissions for all actions on all resources.

I am terraforming an S3 bucket that looks like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "my_bucket"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

}
```

but when I apply the plan I am getting: `Error: error putting S3 server side encryption configuration: AccessDenied: Access Denied`

That is a weird error concerning I am the admin.

Getting the same error in the console:

```
You don't have permissions to edit default encryption
After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration action, choose Save changes.
```

That is **not** true. The `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` policy has the following JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas what is going on?

P.S: I could successfully run the same HCL in another playground account with the same access. It seems I cannot on the one I want to deploy it, which makes zero sense.

Comment: Is your account a member of an organization?

Comment: @kgiannakakis yes.

Comment: There are probably SCPs or permissions boundaries in place preventing your operation.

Comment: You are right, there is a guardrail SCP from ControlTower denying the action.

Comment: You can post as an answer if you wish, I will accept.